# Exporting UV Edit

Tags: texturing, export

So I'm very new to Blender and need help with an issue. I made a model and used an image to texture it. I went into UV Editing and moved some stuff around. The problem is, I don't know how to export the model with the changes I made to the textured areas. Again I'm not very experienced so the answer might be something obvious. Also, the model is a rig.

Comment: if you want to make sure that the image textures you use are part of the blend file, go into the File menu > External Data > Automatically Pack Into Blend

Answer (score 0):

If you export in .fbx or .obj formats it packs UVs automatically.